# Irregular mask size compositor vs movie clip editor

Tags: node-editor, masking

As you can see from the two images below, the mask comes out smaller in the compositor then what I did in the movie clip editor.
Why can I not see the whole dog in the compositor?

[image: mask in the movie clip editor]

[image: mask used in the compositor showing the problem]

Comment: Can anyone solve my this problem? Why I can't get the whole masked region?

Comment: Change the resolution to 100%

Answer (score 3):

Your mask node indicates 'Scene Size' and your scene is set to 50% of the render settings. Try adjusting this to either 100% of the render settings (if they match the image size) or choosing 'Fixed' and setting the actual pixels in X and Y axis.

Comment: Or use a scale node set to 'render size'

Comment: If the answer is useful please accept it as correct by clicking the tick box